# Why does js click function run multiple times?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I'm creating some accordion functionality for fields and paragraphs using a combination of twig templates and a custom JavaScript file.

Everything prints as expected and the basic accordion functionality works; however, the click function script is running multiple times, causing an "expand-collapse-expand-collapse..." behavior. See image:

[image: browser and console view that shows logging of each function iteration on click]

Here is the script file:

```
(function($, Drupal) {

/* Add span to wysiwyg button classes for alignment
------------------------------------ */
Drupal.behaviors.accordionFaqFunction = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
        $('.toggle').click(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);

                if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
                        $this.next().removeClass('show');
                        $this.next().slideUp(350);
                        console.log("hiding");
                } else {
                        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
                        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
                        console.log("showing");
                        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
                        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
                }
        });


  }
};

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Why is the script running multiple times?

Comment: High level guess - because `Drupal.behaviors.attach` is executing multiple times, and you’re not making use of `once` to ensure the event handlers are only bound once

Comment: @Clive that may well be the case - would you please explain in an answer how to best do this for Drupal.Behaviors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most importantly you have to use the JQuery selector `context`. Otherwise you run the entire DOM through your js code anytime when Drupal behaviors passes you only `context` to process.

If your function still runs multiple times, add once() with a unique identifier:

```
$('input.myCustom', context).once('mySecondBehavior').each(function () {
```

Don't forget to add the library `core/jquery.once` to mytheme.libraries.yml, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Answer (score 8):

I just came across this post while working something out in our project. We have multiple events bound to $('body', context) since flexibility in the platform allows for widgets and such to be placed almost anywhere within the body.

Using `$('body', context).on('click', '.modal-trigger', function (e) {});` was causing the click event to be bound on body 2x.

Simply using `$('body', context).once().on('click', '.modal-trigger', function (e) {});` was binding only the last attached/loaded script to the body, resulting in no other script events being attached.

Adding .once() with a unique identifier for each script solved this issue beautifully.

Ex.
1st modal script

```
  Drupal.behaviors.SigmaModal = {

    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Trigger sigma dialog on click.
      $('body', context).once('SigmaModal').on('click', '.sigma-modal-trigger', function (e) {
```

2nd modal script

```
  Drupal.behaviors.DisplayModal = {

    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Trigger generic dialogs on click.
      $('body', context).once('DisplayModal').on('click', '.modal-trigger', function (e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one on Drupal 8:

```
Drupal.behaviors.custom = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        if(!Drupal.behaviors.custom.click_set){
            //Your code.
            Drupal.behaviors.custom.click_set = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add context to the dom object, which will limit execution to a particular context.

Refer to the example below which will fetch data from a remote url.

```
Drupal.behaviors.fetchTermsAndConditions = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $('#clickableElementID', context).on('click', function(){
                var remoteURL = 'https://remotejson.url';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: remoteURL,
                    success: function (data) {
                      {
                        $('#targetElementID').append(data.value);
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }); 
                
            }
      }
    };
```

In addition if the function to be executed on global context uses the html or body context it is Drupals equivalent to `$(document).ready( myInit() );`

Read more on the Drupal documentation here
https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview